# form validation in Django, client site angular/javascript

Tags: ajax, django, angularjs

I want bind data sent by ajax to django form. Inside view I'm trying to bind data something like this:

```
form = RhymeForm(request.body)
# request.body: {"content":"<p>a</p>","title":""}
```

I cant get any validation errors, so how to bind data send by ajax to form?

Comment: I would advise to perform as much validation (if not all) inside angular directly. Much easier and better user experience.

Comment: @LukeSkywalker I asked about binding data, not validate

Answer (score 1):

`request.body` is just text payload. To use it as the data for the form, you should unpack it first:

```
form = RhymeForm(json.loads(request.body))
```

Comment: after binding this way the form not working: Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Process `json.loads(request.body)` separately and check what exactly does it return - it should be a `dict`